# Hiding certain file extensions in cloud9 (self hosted)

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide

I am hosting cloud9 on my own server, and would like to hide certain file extensions from the explorer view/pane.

I've spent some time trying to figure out how to do it, with no luck. From my research, there is a filelist extension built into cloud9 that supports it, but I can not figure out how to do it.

If anyone knows how this can be done, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!